# Number of distinct prime factors, omega(n)

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization

Is there a formula that can tell us how many distinct prime factors a number has?
We have closed form solutions for the number of factors a number has and the sum of those factors but not the number of distinct prime factors.

So for example:
\begin{array}{rr}
\text{number} & \text{distinct}\atop \text{prime factors} \\
1&0 \\
2&1 \\
3&1 \\
4&1 \\
5&1 \\
6&2 \\
7&1 \\
8&1 \\
9&1 \\
10&2 
\end{array}

Comment: What closed form solutions are you referring to?  If you mean $d(n) = \prod_{p^r \| n} (r+1)$ then what is wrong with $\omega(n) = \sum_{p \mid n} 1$?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is a historically interesting question as it led Hardy and Ramanujan to lay the foundation to probabilistic number theory in course of their solution to this problem. Given $n$ there is no non-trivial deterministic closed form formula for the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. However we have very good probabilistic formula for the same.

> Hardy and Ramanujan proved that for almost all integers, the number is
>   distinct primes dividing a number $n$ is 
>   formula
>
> $$ \omega(n) \sim \log\log n. $$

We can do much better than the Hardy-Ramanujan estimate and find and estimate of $\omega(n)$ which can be bounded by normal distribution. Erdos and Kac imporved the estimate of $\omega(n)$ and proved that

> $$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x}\# \Big\{n\le x, \frac{\omega(n) -
>  \log\log n}{\sqrt{\log\log n}} \le t \Big\} =
>  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{t}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}du $$

This formula says that if $n$ is a large number, we can estimate the distribution of the number of prime factors for numbers of this range. For example we can show that around 12.6% of 10,000 digit numbers are constructed from 10 distinct prime numbers and around 68% (±$\sigma$) are constructed from between 7 and 13 distinct primes.

Comment: "for almost all integers, the number is distinct primes dividing a number $n$ is given by the asymptotic formula" does not make sense. Asymptotic formulas do not apply to individual instances; you wouldn't be able to cite a single number $n$ for which the formula _gives_ its number of distinct primes.

Comment: Yeah asymptotic is not the right word, but the result remains the same. This is a probabilistic result.

Comment: I see nothing random at all in the formulation.

Comment: Well then for a more precise formulation, you might want to refer to http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hardy-RamanujanTheorem.html and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erdos-KacTheorem.html

Comment: And that statement involves an expression $\sqrt{\ln\ln x}$, which cannot be taken out without the statement losing its meaning.

Comment: Thats why we need the Erdos-Kac's version which result takes care of that assumption in Hardy-Ramanujan's version. Erdos Kac they proved normal distribution in any interval (a,b).

Answer (score 6):

This is commonly known as $\omega(n)$.  See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_function#.CF.89.28n.29_.E2.80.93_distinct_prime_divisors).

Answer (score 4):

We do *not* have the closed form solutions you claim.
We have formulas that assume that we know the
prime factorization.

Comment: I am interested in counting  $\sum_{i \le N} |\omega(i)=4|$ . was wondering if you could help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to calculate $\omega(n)$ for a large range of $n$, it's simple to modify the Sieve of Eratosthenes to count distinct prime factors. Instead of marking multiples of each prime, keep a counter for every number and increment instead of marking. [SO code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17638003/3163618)