# Upper Bound on Number of Factors

Tags: factoring

Is there a theorem, lemma, or proof somewhere that proves an upper bound for the number of factors that a number can have?

If not, would it be fairly trivial to prove that it is $log_2 n$?

Comment: The number of factors is $o(n^\epsilon)$ for every positive $\epsilon$, but it can be much larger than $\log n$. Or did you mean prime factors?

Comment: I didn't mean prime factors, which means that something is off in my thinking.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how many prime factors are there?

Comment: Never mind. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938204/upper-bound-number-of-distinct-prime-factors

Comment: Also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409675/number-of-distinct-prime-factors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

given that log2(24) is approx. 4.5, but 24 has 8 factors. I have to say, that this is not an upper bound. 
I personal looked for an upper bound recently to the number of factors function and I got sqrt(3*x), it might not be the tightest upper bound. but it works.
look at the image bellow

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bWW9.png

Comment: (39*x)^(1/3) is probably a tighter upper bound. again I got this from plotting the # of factors function, I did not do a formal proof.

Answer (score 3):

Let ${d(n)}$ denote the number of factors of $n$.

There is a useful bound which has applications in many area:

${d(n)\le n^{O(1/\log \log n)} = \exp(O(\frac{\log n}{\log\log n}))}$.

Maybe Tao's blog can help you understand the answer better.

https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/09/23/the-divisor-bound/