# Finding primitive root mod n?

Tags: algorithms, finite-fields, primitive-roots

in wikipedia, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n#Finding_primitive_roots,

it says there is no formula to compute primitive root mod n. and in the footnote 8, it seems that there are no fast algorithm neither.

but isn't that algorithm shown in this link fast enough? I mean, calculating modular exponentiation can be $O(\log n)$ fast, so this algorithm looks at most $O(n\log n)$. it's better than $O(n^2)$, so seems fast enough.

am I misunderstanding somewhere about time complexity analysis? or is it just not fast enough?

Comment: I believe the question is whether the primitive root of a $d$-digit number can be found quickly.  If $n$ is a $d$-digit number, then $n$ is on the order of $10^d$.

Comment: @WillOrrick but isn't that all same? like, the merge sort is $O(n\log n)$, if we let $n=10^d$ or something, it becomes $O(d10^d)$. for any polynomial-fast algorithm, if we replace it to use digits as input, they all go exponential.

Comment: In sorting, the input is the list of items to be supported, which has size proportional to $n$.  In arithmetic, the inputs are the numbers to be acted upon, whose length is their number of digits.  Basic arithmetic operations such as addition, multiplication, and finding square roots are practical because their complexity is polynomial in the number of digits.  If the algorithms were polynomial in the magnitude of the numbers themselves, arithmetic would bog down quickly.  The question is whether finding primitive roots can be done as quickly as, say, finding square roots.

Comment: @WillOrrick then the methods in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation, are slow if it is $O(n)$, because in digits it is $O(10^d)$, and fast if it is $O(\log n)$, because in digits it is $O(d)$, right?

Comment: That's right.  In the linked article, the goal is to compute $b^e\mod m$.  If $b$ has $r$ digits, $e$ has $s$ digits, and $m$ has $t$ digits, then the straightforward method and the memory-efficient method both take time exponential in $s$ (but only polynomial in $r$ and $t$).  The right-to-left binary method is polynomial in all three.

Comment: @WillOrrick Thank you very much! it all makes sense now :)

Comment: @WillOrrick again, sorry, I thought it was clear, and then I realized that if I use right-to-left method for modular exponentiation, and the fact that the number of distinct prime dividing n is $O(\log \log n)$ from http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409675/number-of-distinct-prime-factors, then the method given in Wiki is $O(\log n \log \log n)$, which is $O(d\log d)$ in terms of digits, $n=10^d$. ...again, isn't it fast enough?

Comment: Don't you have to repeat this for many numbers $m$ relatively prime to $n$?  If the number of different $m$ you have to try before finding a primitive root is $O(n)$, then it is still slow.  Also, finding the prime factors of $n$ is itself [difficult](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization).

Comment: @WillOrrick if I have to find all the primitive roots, then yes. but if I just want to know whether some specific $a$ is a primitive root mod $p$ or not, then it takes $O(d\log d)$, I think. and yes finding the prime factors of $n$, or $p-1$ is hard but if we just use the work that gives just an information about time complexity, as i linked there, then at least we can calculate the complexity of the algorithm, can't we?

Comment: In my previous comment, [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization#Difficulty_and_complexity) would have been a better link.  Are you referring to the number of distinct prime factors result?  That is not a complexity result; it tells you how many distinct prime factors you expect to find on average, but does not tell you how difficult they are to find.  Of course it is true that determining whether a given number is a primitive root is less difficult than finding a primitive root.  I'm not an expert, but I suspect it is still difficult.