# Suppose $p(n)$ is the number of prime that $n$ can be divisible by, what is $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{p(n)}{n}$?

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory

Some example:

$27=3\cdot 3\cdot 3$, hence $p(27)=1$;

$26=2\cdot 13$, hence $p(26)=2$.

---

I tried to solve the problem by matlab. And I've found that $\max\limits_{1\leqslant n\leqslant 10^k}\quad p(n)=k+1$ by some test. Then for any $n$, there exists a $k\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $n<10^k$. Hence, $\frac{1}{n}\leqslant \frac{p(n)}{n}\leqslant \frac{10^k}{n}$, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{p(n)}{n}=0$.

The question is : How to prove my guess? In other words, why $\max\limits_{1\leqslant n\leqslant 10^k}\quad p(n)=k+1$?

Comment: This is $\omega(n)/n$.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409675/number-of-distinct-prime-factors-omegan for more on this.

Comment: The trivial estimate $n\ge 2^{p(n)}$ is good enough

Answer (score 0):

We don't need any heavy duty theorems.

If $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$, then $\tau(n) \le \sqrt{n}$, as if $a\cdot b = n$ then at least one of them is $\le \sqrt{n}$.

And so

$$0 \le \frac{\omega(n)}{n} \le \frac{\tau(n)}{n} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$$

Apply the sandwich theorem.

Comment: That just tells you that $\omega(n)=O(n^{1/2})$, which is a lot weaker than even $\omega(n)=O(\log(n))$. So I don't think it achieves the desired result of the OP. It merely proves what the OP already knew to be true.

Comment: @Ian: I was going by the title. Seems like OP snuck another question at the end, which I missed.