# Positive integer $m≤n$ such that $m$ has the largest number of distinct prime factors among all positive integers $\le n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

How do I interpret the following mathematically:

Consider a positive integer $n$ such that $n=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_m^{\alpha_m}$ where $p_i$ are primes and $\alpha_i$ are positive integers.

I want to consider the positive integer $m\le n$ such that $m$ has the largest number of distinct prime factors among all positive integers less than or equal to $n$.

I explain it with the following example:

Consider $n=36$. Here my $m$ will be $30$ since $30=2\times 3\times 5$ and it has the largest number of distinct prime factors among all positive integers which are less than or equal to $n=36$.

But I cant express my view mathematically.
How do I present my mathematical idea?
Can someone please help me to write the above fact in a more precise and concise manner which can be easily understood by mathematicians.

Please help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/409675/number-of-distinct-prime-factors-omegan

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan; I never asked in my question to find the number of prime factors of an integer, i needed help with writing my concept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the largest positive integer $\ k\ $ with $\ p_k$#$\le n\ $

Then, there is a number not exceeding $\ n\ $ , namely $\ p_k$# , with $\ k\ $ distinct prime factors and a number with $\ k+1\ $ or more distinct prime factors must be at least $\ p_{k+1}$#$>n\ $

Hence , the desired number is $\ m=p_k$# , in other words, the largest primorial not exceeding $\ n\ $.

Comment: What is meant by `#`?

Comment: Can you please provide more details

Comment: $p$# stands for $\ 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdots p\ $.(called "primorial")

Comment: It is easy to show that the primorial with the primes upto the $\ k\ $-th prime is the smallest positive integer with at least $\ k\ $ distinct prime factors.

Comment: What does `primorial` mean? I am sorry but is it possible to give a more detailed answer

Comment: Similar to the factorial : The primorial is the product of all primes not exceeding the  argument (which is usually a prime, but we can define the primorial also for composite numbers). With $p_k$ I simply mean the $k$-th prime number.

Comment: oh okay, thanks for clarifying

Comment: given any positive integer $n$, is it possible to find $k$?

Comment: I am not aware of a better method than brute force. Just keep multiplying with the next prime until you exceed $n$, then remove the last prime.

Comment: okay , thanks a lot